# Django: Send reminder email

Tags: django, scheduled-tasks, reminders

my app has list of events with start time (date and time). I want to make a scheduled task to send reminder via email to all user participate in event 1 hour before event start. (Note: Admin can change time of event).

I currently use celery to send email to list of participants when admin change the time of event.

Please suggest me some solution for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recent(ish) discussion where a potential solution is proposed for celery: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/4522.

I built [Posthook](https://posthook.io) to make solving these kinds of problems easier for developers. In your case, when a new event is created or the event time changes you can schedule a request back to your app for 1 hour before the start time. Then when you get the request from Posthook you can send out the reminder after validating that it still needs to be sent out.